# Can't uninstall package because dpkg fails for the package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am stuck, I can't seem to use apt-get properly anymore because there is this package `timidity-daemon` that keeps "failing" whenever I run apt-get.

What is worse is that I can't uninstall `timidity-daemon` because of this error, which is completely ridiculous IMHO.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove timidity-daemon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  timidity-daemon
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 31.7 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 240280 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing timidity-daemon (2.13.2-40.3) ...
Failed to stop timidity.service: Unit timidity.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript timidity, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package timidity-daemon (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Failed to stop timidity.service: Unit timidity.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript timidity, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 timidity-daemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any idea how I can fix this? I'm not even sure why timidity-daemon was installed in the first place, but I don't think I need it.